# i want to getSavedUri() of saved video file

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, uri, absolute-path

i have made a simple camera application using cameraX api to record 10 sec video. app is working fine it records 10 sec video and save it into internal mobile storage but i want to get absolute path where the app is storing videos. iam using getsaveduri method to get the absolute path of saved video file using outputfileresult but the code is not working

```
    private fun captureVideo() {
    val videoCapture = this.videoCapture ?: return
    val curRecording = recording
    if (curRecording != null) {
        // Stop the current recording session.
        curRecording.stop()
        recording = null
        return
    }

    // create and start a new recording session
    val name = SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US)
        .format(System.currentTimeMillis())
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Movies/CameraX-Video")
        }
    }
    
         val mediaStoreOutputOptions = MediaStoreOutputOptions
        .Builder(contentResolver, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        .setContentValues(contentValues)
        .build()
    recording = videoCapture.output
        .prepareRecording(this, mediaStoreOutputOptions)
        .apply {
            if (PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(this@MainActivity,
                    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) ==
                PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                withAudioEnabled()
            }

        }
        .start(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this)) {

        }
    onVideoSaved(outputFileResults = androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture.OutputFileResults)


    **@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private fun onVideoSaved(outputFileResults: OutputFileResults) {
    val uri: Uri? = outputFileResults.savedUri
}**
```

this is where iam using uti to get absolute path of saved video file

Comment: `iam using getsaveduri method ` I do not see that method. Nor that you are calling it.

Comment: val uri: Uri? = outputFileResults.savedUri   i am calling i here.. savedUri method is getsaveduri @blackapps

Comment: "the code is not working" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo whenever i was passing outputfileresults to onVideoSaved function it does not allow me to pass the parameter.. this is the code.           onVideoSaved(outputFileResults = androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture.OutputFileResults)


    **@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private fun onVideoSaved(outputFileResults: OutputFileResults) {
    val uri: Uri? = outputFileResults.savedUri
}**

Comment: check out my youtube playlist here https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlSuJy9SfzvGEeoalzMz-VA5ohI0LzSKH

Comment: i hope you understand